# Is there anything simple for debugger visualizers in C# that's analogous to editing autoexp.dat for C++?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

I have a class that has a few simple members I'm looking to expose to the debugger in Visual Studio 2010. I want to quickly glance over a list of these types and avoid all the drilling and expanding of the variable's value tree. I'm hoping there's something quick to go by analogous to editing autoexp.dat like in C++.

Comment: I don't know much about C++, but you are probably looking for the DebuggerDisplay attribute. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

Comment: Sweet, looks like that link discusses autoexp.cs! That's the sort of analogous thing I was looking for. I'll check out these attributes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `ToString()` for your objects, or use [DebuggerDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) (thanks @gdir).

> If a C# object has an overridden ToString(), the debugger will call
>   the override and show its result instead of the standard {}.
>   Thus, if you have overridden ToString(), you do not have to use
>   DebuggerDisplay. If you use both, the DebuggerDisplay attribute takes
>   precedence over the ToString() override.